# Show file contents after searching word Done

Tags: linux, bash, file, text

I need to display the file contents after searching for a word. If the word is found, display the file.

My code is below:

GNU nano 2.2.6                                              File: work

```
#!/bin/bash


while read -p "Welcome what would you like to do (S) to search or (Q) to quit  "  option
do
case $option in
        "S")    echo "What is the name of the file you would like to search for?"
                read file
                echo "What word would you like to find in the file?"
                read word
                grep -q $word $file
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                echo "$word found in $file"
                cat $file
                else
                echo "$word NOT found in $file"
                fi
                ;;

        "Q")    echo "Goodbye!"
                exit ;;

          *)    echo "invalid option" ;;
esac
done
```

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible bad english.

Comment: im sorry i have dislexia

Comment: ok. So try to reformulate or describe your problem in another way. Don't be shy to be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
echo $file
```

with

```
cat $file
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for command `cat $file`. Stick it inside of your `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to load up what a file says with out loading up the file.

There is no way to access the contents of the file without accessing the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -l word file | xargs -r cat
```

shows file content if word is found. This also shows name of file

```
grep -l word file | xargs -r -i bash -c "echo {}:; cat {}"
```